# Which outputs to use on my mixer

Tags: guitar, piano, software, recording

I'm looking at doing some simple recording at home, and I'm looking to buy a [Behringer 1202 12 mixer](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/1202.aspx), or something of similar price or quality. The devices I'll need to record are as follows:

- A digital piano
- A guitar (from the output of an amp)
- An iPad (possibly 2) (for drums, sfx etc.)

What I'm wondering is, which outputs from the mixer do I use? I'd like to do the following with the audio:

- Be able to listen to it live in headphones/monitors
- Be able to send it to main speakers (for a performance)
- Be able to send it to a computer for recording

For reference, [here is a picture of the mixer with it's outputs](http://images.sdj.netdna-cdn.com/D/Behringer-1202-XENYX-12-Input-2-Bus-Mixer-with-Mic-Preamps-detailed-image.png). The mixer has FX send, phones, control room, L/R and CD/Tape outputs - which of these would I use for each of the above uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that this is set up for what you want:

- The "phones" output (which is probably stereo) would be for your headphones,
- The "mains" outputs could go to your monitors, and
- The "control room" outputs could go to your recording device.

In general, you should prefer the 1/4" jacks over the RCA style inputs/outputs of the "tape" section.

Comment: It's basically a set-up I've used for several years. You are always better 'monitoring' on cans through the recording desk if poss.Your output 'to speakers' will need to go through an amp. first.Where are you going to take the signal from on the guitar amp?

Comment: When you get the mixer have a look at the block diagram for the mixer electronics.  It will tell you which FX are passed through to which output.  For instance you may want to hear your reverb on the vocals, but you may want to record without it.  There is a button as well where you send the FX to the headphones/control room.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to record those as separate tracks then this device will not help you as it is only a mixer. You need a digital audio interface if you want to record and later on want to edit each track. If this is what you want then you buy an interface with as many inputs as you require. Yo. Need 5 inputs based in your list.

There are also mixers with. Uild in audio interface that you connect with usb or firewire to your pc or mac.